# How to add multiple models together in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some number inputs as so:

```
<input class="title form-control" id="quantity1" min="0" name="quantity1" ng-model="option1" type="number" value="0">
<input class="title form-control" id="quantity2" min="0" name="quantity2" ng-model="option2" type="number" value="0">
<input class="title form-control" id="quantity3" min="0" name="quantity3" ng-model="option3" type="number" value="0">
<input class="title form-control" id="quantity4" min="0" name="quantity4" ng-model="option4" type="number" value="0">
```

And in other number input I want to display the total quantity.

```
<input class="title form-control" id="quantity" min="0" name="quantity" ng-model="quantityTotal" type="number" value="0">
```

How would I go about adding multiple bindings together.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: You can make use of value attribute of the control over here. So it would be like:

```
<input  class="title form-control" id="quantity" min="0" name="quantity" value="{{option1+option2+option3+option4}}" type="number" />
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8hjh6mm/)

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods that readily jump to mind.

First you could use ng-change to call a function to update the total:

HTML:

```
 <input class="title form-control" id="quantity1" min="0" name="quantity1" ng-change="onQuantityChange()" ng-model="option1" type="number">
 <input class="title form-control" id="quantity2" min="0" name="quantity2" ng-change="onQuantityChange()" ng-model="option2" type="number">
 <input class="title form-control" id="quantity3" min="0" name="quantity3" ng-change="onQuantityChange()" ng-model="option3" type="number">
 <input class="title form-control" id="quantity4" min="0" name="quantity4" ng-change="onQuantityChange()" ng-model="option4" type="number">

 <input class="title form-control" id="quantity" min="0" name="quantity" type="number" ng-model="quantityTotal">
```

Function:

```
$scope.onQuantityChange = function() {
    $scope.quantityTotal = $scope.option1 + $scope.option2 + $scope.option3 + $scope.option4;
  };
```

You could also just add an expression to the value of the total input like so:

```
<input class="title form-control" id="quantity" min="0" name="quantity" type="number" value="{{opt1+opt2+opt3+opt4}}">
```

Here are both solutions working on [plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/t8jPc8wOg0zLVuOzjc1I?p=preview)

Side note the first approach would probably be the preferred as it is generally good practice to avoid putting your business logic into your markup.

Hope this helps. Cheers!